How to install r8168-dkm without internet
After updating Ubuntu 24.04 LTS the internet stopped working. The lshw -C network command showed that the network was unclaimed. I downloaded the r8168-dkm package from the realtek website and installed it using the shell but it kept giving the following error:
Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'clean'. Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:182: clean] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:48: clean] Error 2

I also tried installing it from the deb file using GDebi Package Installer but it did not work.

Realtek doesn't have a r8168-dkms package.  That is a package that was built for Ubuntu in the Ubuntu repositories.  Whoever maintains the r8168-dkms package for Ubuntu has updated the driver version to 8.052.01 which should work fine with 24.04 LTS.
You can download the actual package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/r8168-dkms and then run sudo apt install ./nameoffile.deb from a command line.
In this case it would be running the following from the actual directory that contains the downloaded file:
sudo apt install ./r8168-dkms_8.052.01-1ubuntu1_all.deb

In the answer I wrote here, it shows a way that if you download the driver from Realtek that you can convert the driver over to a DKMS install.
Hope this helps!
